# How to root cause a bazel py_test target yielding a 0/0 remote cache hit rate

Tags: bazel

I have this test target going roughly like...

```py
py_test(
    name = "test_foo",
    srcs = [
        "test_foo.py",
    ],
    data = [
        "//sw_bar:big_binary_baz",
    ],
    args = [
        "--junit-xml=test-reports/test_foo.xml",
    ],
    tags = [
        "exclusive",
        "no-remote-exec",
        "requires-network",
    ],
)
```

Because that test is running on select hardware we need to run it local to a special test rig. However when run with our remote build config we're seeing the following report regarding the cache hit rate for the remote actions.

```
INFO: Cache hit rate for remote actions: -- (0 / 0)
```

The `no-remote-exec` tag was thought to be appropriate since we don't want this test executing on remote agents. Is that interfering with the test host publishing test results to the remote cache? Am I mistaken in thinking that I can combine a remote build of the test binaries, have them execute locally on a particular machine, and have that result instance published back to the remote cache?

We're basically running some HIL tests which are pretty expensive and sometimes flaky. We were really hoping to dodge running them at all by heavily leveraging the remote cache if anyone at our organization is running the same software as someone else.

Comment: How big is `big_binary_baz`? How big can the artifacts be that can be handled by our remote cache?

Comment: That name was more figurative than anything substantive. Looks like running `ls -l --block-size=MB big_binary_baz` comes back with a figure of 1MB, makes sense since this is really a firmware target so can't be too huge. You think the size of the binary could be implicated possibly?